# How do I go about and Find Min Max Values in a Kotlin App

Tags: android, kotlin

**I made a stat calculator and I need to store 10 user inputted values to be stored in an array where I can get the average and lowest number. How do I go about getting the values on the array to get the maximum and minimum values?**

```
    var values = ArrayList<Int>()
    var count = 0
    var arrCount = 0


    addButt.setOnClickListener {


        values.add(statNum.text.toString().toInt())
        count++
        arrCount++
        var i = 0
        statNum.setText("")
        statArray.text = ""
        for (i in 0..arrCount - 1) {
            statArray.text = statArray.text as String + values[i] + ","
        }

    }


    avgBut.setOnClickListener{
        val statArray = doubleArrayOf(4.0, 7.0, 11.0, 12.0, 9.0)
        var sum = 0.0

        for (num in statArray) {
            sum += num
        }

        val average = sum / statArray.size
        finalAnswer.text = average.toString()
    }

    minmaxBut.setOnClickListener{

        fun findMin(list: List<Int?>): Int? {
            return list.sortedWith(compareBy { it }).first()
        }

        fun findMax(list: List<Int?>): Int? {
            return list.sortedWith(compareBy { it }).last()
        }

        fun main() {
            val list = listOf(10, 4, 2, 7, 6, 9)

            val min = findMin(list)
            finalAnswer.text = "Min Vale = $min"

            val max = findMax(list)
            println(max)            // 10
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's very easy to get `min`, `max` and `average` number in the arraylist. I did not understand your code clearly but i will share how you can do these. After you may use that on your array:

```
val list = arrayListOf<Int>(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
        Log.e("min", list.min().toString())
        Log.e("max", list.max().toString())
        Log.e("average", list.average().toString())
```

This will give you below output in logcat:

```
E/min: 1
E/max: 10
E/average: 5.5
```